# Can't use ref-parameters and use generated table columns with the same data

Tags: c#

Here's the objective.  To be able to use ConvertLength with a ref parameter, and AutoGenerateColumns.  But as far as I can figure, fields ("b") cannot be used to generate columns, and properties ("c") cannot be used as references.  Is there a resolution?

```
class A
{
    public decimal b;
    public decimal c { get ; set ; }
}

void ConvertLength(ref decimal field)
{
   field = field * 2.0m;
}

class x : Form
{
  DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

  a[] rows = new a[5];  
  ConvertLength(ref a[0].b); 
  ConvertLength(ref a[0].c); 
  dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
  dgv.DataSource = rows;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you make ConvertLength return a decimal then set the field and the property equal to the result of calling the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx):

> Properties are not variables. They are methods, and cannot be passed to `ref` parameters.

So you cannot pass `A.c` in to `ConvertLength`. You *could* pass `b`, but note that you'd have to use the `ref` keyword:

```
ConvertLength(ref a[0].b);
```

Note that `b` will also have to be accessible to class `x` (e.g. `public` or `internal` if `x` is in the same assembly). And also your `ConvertLength` method will need to use `2.0m` as a decimal literal rather than `2.0` which is a double.

You almost never need to use `ref` parameters, and if you are using them, it's usually an indication of other issues (i.e. [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)). If it were me, I'd follow [@Tbid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586899/cant-use-ref-parameters-and-use-generated-table-columns-with-the-same-data#comment72306187_42586899)'s suggestion, like this:

```
decimal ConvertLength(decimal field) => field * 2.0m;

...
a[0].b = ConvertLength(a[0].b); 
a[0].c = ConvertLength(a[0].c); // works with properties or fields.
```

But if you *really* need to have one class that has fields for the sake of `ref` parameters and properties for the sake of `AutoGenerateColumns`, you could always do this:

```
class A
{
    public decimal b_field;
    public decimal b { get { return b_field; } set { b_field = value; } }

    public decimal c_field
    public decimal c { get { return c_field; } set { c_field = value; } }
}

...
ConvertLength(ref a[0].b_field); 
ConvertLength(ref a[0].c_field);
```

Comment: Oops. Made corrections to the question, regarding the use of public and ref.  Okay so properties can't be passed as ref.  Can a table use class fields?  Is there an option C that allows both?